# How to get changes that have been integrated within a CL range?

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

Given src and dest branches, how do I find what was integrated from src within dest/...@lower,upper?

P4.run_integrated complains that it doesn't accept revision specs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ p4 changes dest/...@lower,upper returns the changes submitted into dest.
$ p4 changes -i dest/...@lower,upper includes the changes that were integrated into dest.
```

The difference between the latter and the former are the changes integrated into dest.

Using p4python one would have something like:

```
changes = set(P4.run_integrated('dest/...@lower,upper'))
changes_with_integrated = set(P4.run_integrated('-i', 'dest/...@lower,upper'))
integrated_changes = changes_with_integrated.difference(changes)
```

Comment: Your changes and changes_with_integrated are both set to the exact same thing, so that is going to produce an empty set.